# Substrate Stencil node not producing blocks

Tags: block-production

I forked the [Substrate Stencil](https://github.com/kaichaosun/substrate-stencil) node to kickstart from Governance and Staking. I've followed the steps from both the repo and [Substrate docs](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/private-network). I tried to run a staging node but it's idling with 4 validator peers.

Steps I've done;

- Build a custom spec file with created keys.
- Start the nodes
- Insert keys to each node
- Restart the nodes to see if it makes it any different

The commands I use can be found in this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/buraktabn/17f26f8dd83117710fbb670f9dacb136).

I suspect that I'm doing something wrong with the keys but can't figure out what's that exactly.

Comment: This source is unmodified? What are your node logs?

Comment: Yes, I just updated `customSpec.json` and created a new raw spec. Logs are just idling. I've managed to solve the issue. I knew It wasn't a good question but it worked as a totem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that using derive when creating keys for authoring and finalization doesn't go well together.

What I've been doing:

```
./target/release/substrate-stencil key inspect --password-interactive --scheme Sr25519 "<secret>//1//babe"

./target/release/substrate-stencil key inspect --password-interactive --scheme Ed25519 "<secret>//1//grandpa"
```

What's working:

```
./target/release/substrate-stencil key generate --scheme Sr25519 --password-interactive

./target/release/substrate-stencil key inspect --password-interactive --scheme Ed25519 <secret-from-above>
```